# rename columns for group of data frames using name()

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I would like to rename a bunch of data frames with name function but not able to use lapply or loop.

I have group of data frames name qcew.2007, qcew.2014, etc... I have vector with name I would like all of data frame to have. They are all the same.  the vector is name colnm:

```
colnm = c("area_fips" , "own_code", "industry_code", "agglvl_code") # example shortened
 # groups has names of all data frames and goes to 2013
group =c("qcew.2007", "qcew.2008", "qcew.2009") 
    # using lapply
    names <- lapply(group, function(d){
     n = paste0(d)
     names(n) = colnm
    })
# using loop does not work either
   for (i in seq(group)) {
   names(group[[i]]) = colnm 
}
```

Neither option works, as it is saying I am comparing vectors with uneven lengths. I must be missing something obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You need to use `get` otherwise you're assigning names to the character vectors in `group`:

```
# sample data
qcew.2007 <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
qcew.2008 <- data.frame(a=3, b=4, c=5, d=6)
qcew.2009 <- data.frame(a=5, b=6, c=7, d=8)    


for(i in 1:3)
    assign(group[i], `names<-`(get(group[i]), colnm))
names(qcew.2007)
# [1] "area_fips"     "own_code"      "industry_code" "agglvl_code"  
names(qcew.2008)
# [1] "area_fips"     "own_code"      "industry_code" "agglvl_code"  
names(qcew.2009)
# [1] "area_fips"     "own_code"      "industry_code" "agglvl_code"
```

Here you use `get` to get the object named in each position in `group` and then use `assign` to reassign the modified object (modified by changing column names) back into that named object.

Comment: Can you tell me why there is no space on the ** `names<-`** part? thanks for tip on get. I was using the assign in code to create this but did not know about get.

Comment: @muraenok That's a way to express everything in one line. It is the same as `x <- get(group[i]); names(x) <- colnm; assign(group[i], x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
 list2env(lapply(mget(group), setNames, colnm),envir=.GlobalEnv)

 names(qcew.2007)
 #[1] "area_fips"     "own_code"      "industry_code" "agglvl_code"
```